# how to create custom contact list with checkbox

Tags: android, android-contacts

how to create custom contact list with checkbox to select multiple contacts from list in android

```
public class AddFromContacts extends Activity {
ArrayList<String> listname;
// ArrayList<String> list_no;
Context context;
LayoutInflater inflater;
ListView contactlistView;
String name;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.show);

contactlistView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.ContactlistView);

listname = new ArrayList<String>();
// list_no = new ArrayList<String>();

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
Cursor cur = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
        null, null, null);
if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
    while (cur.moveToNext()) {
        String id = cur.getString(cur
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

        String name = cur
                .getString(cur
                                    .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
        if (Integer
                .parseInt(cur.getString(cur
                        .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {

            Cursor pCur = cr.query(
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                    null,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID
                            + " = ?", new String[] { id }, null);
            while (pCur.moveToNext()) {
                // Do something with phones
                String phoneNo = pCur
                        .getString(pCur
                                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                listname.add(name + "\n" + phoneNo);

                // list_no.add(phoneNo);

            }
            pCur.close();
        }
    }

}
contactlistView.setAdapter(new Contact(this));
}

class Contact extends BaseAdapter {
Context myContext;

public Contact(AddFromContacts contactActivity) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.myContext = contactActivity;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return listname.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (convertView == null) {

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) myContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.checkbox, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text_name = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.name);
        viewHolder.id = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.id);
        viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.checkBox);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }

    final ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    // holder.text_name.setText(list_no.get(position));
    holder.id.setText(listname.get(position));

    if (holder != null) {
        holder.checkBox
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    public void onCheckedChanged(
                            CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        // Toast.makeText(myContext, name + "     Selected",
                        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
    }
    return convertView;
}
}

class ViewHolder {
TextView text_name, id;
CheckBox checkBox;
// EditText search;
}
}
```

but i am facing problem with this at the time of select contacts from list it select those contacts from the list which are not selected by me

Comment: did you try the below

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Display.java

```
public class Display extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener{

    List<String> name1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> phno1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    MyAdapter ma ;
    Button select;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display);

        getAllContacts(this.getContentResolver());
        ListView lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
            ma = new MyAdapter();
            lv.setAdapter(ma);
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(this); 
            lv.setItemsCanFocus(false);
            lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
            // adding
           select = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        select.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    StringBuilder checkedcontacts= new StringBuilder();

                for(int i = 0; i < name1.size(); i++)

                    {
                    if(ma.mCheckStates.get(i)==true)
                    {
                         checkedcontacts.append(name1.get(i).toString());
                         checkedcontacts.append("\n");

                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }


                }

                Toast.makeText(Display.this, checkedcontacts,1000).show();
            }       
        });


    }
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         ma.toggle(arg2);
    }

    public  void getAllContacts(ContentResolver cr) {

        Cursor phones = cr.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null, null);
        while (phones.moveToNext())
        {
          String name=phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
          String phoneNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
          name1.add(name);
          phno1.add(phoneNumber);
        }

        phones.close();
     }
    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
    {  private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
       LayoutInflater mInflater;
        TextView tv1,tv;
        CheckBox cb;
        MyAdapter()
        {
            mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(name1.size());
            mInflater = (LayoutInflater)Display.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return name1.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            View vi=convertView;
            if(convertView==null)
             vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null); 
             tv= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
             tv1= (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
             cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
             tv.setText("Name :"+ name1.get(position));
             tv1.setText("Phone No :"+ phno1.get(position));
             cb.setTag(position);
             cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
             cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

            return vi;
        }
         public boolean isChecked(int position) {
                return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
            }

            public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
                mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);
            }

            public void toggle(int position) {
                setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
            }
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);         
        }   
    }   
}
```

display.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <ListView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_above="@+id/button1"

       android:id="@+id/lv"/>

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/button1"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
         android:text="Select" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Explanation:

The above uses a Custom Adapter. A custom layout `row.xml` with 2 textviews and one checkbox is inflated for each row. `getAllContacts()` will get all contacts from the contacts list and you store them in a list.

Custom Adapter displays the items in a custom layout inflated for each row.

When you check the check box and click display displays a toast with selected contacts name.

Use a view holder for smooth scrolling and performance. I have not used a view holder.

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Snap shot

[image]

Comment: great bro working fine thanks for your help if want can also mark my question for vote up

Comment: Great job! Could you extend it to save checked items? (when activity starts, previously selected items should remain checked)

Comment: @keybee use shared preferences

Comment: done :) - now I am trying to add an AlphabetIndexer to the list, but it is not working. Could you check it if I send the code? (where should I post my code? A new question?) Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you help me out how make this list searchable ,

Comment: perfect answer i was searching

Comment: @Raghunandan HI. Please check this once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24774840/google-map-shows-south-africa-as-the-current-location

Comment: @PiYusHGuPtA not sure of the problem

Comment: @Raghunandan I have suffered for many times. Please if there any solution because i have tried all things what i knew.

Comment: @Shikhar use a cursor loader for better peformance. Check the contacts if there are duplicates. Some contacts are on sim card and some are on phone. So check that also

Comment: theres only contct on phone as per i see,

Comment: @Shikhar i have not idea why you have duplicates. Try the logging some info and debug. But this approach is not good use a loader its much more efficient.

Comment: Sir Can you give me an example? to use cursor loader and to show name number with respective chekboxes..im in a need urgent thnkyou for ur help

Comment: @Shikhar http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/02/query-contacts-database-using-loader.html

Comment: Sir it doesnt show me phone number thats where i stucked from last 3 hours

Comment: How would I use shared preferences for keeping contacts checked? I have been searching for 3 hours now! Thanks so much :)