# Fetch Contacts from phone book to ListView with checkboxes

Tags: android, android-listview, android-contacts, android-checkbox

For my application, when i click a button "Pick Contacts", i want Phone Contact Book will gets open having check-boxes so that i can select 5 contacts and then these contacts will gets displayed in the list view on my Main Activity. I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605768/how-to-create-custom-contact-list-with-checkbox) example but its not working for me. Can anybody suggest me some tutorials or better links for this

Comment: that is impossible currently, if you are pointing to whatsup or viber picking contact. what they are doing is.. they fetch all the user and add them to a listView with checkboxes.. you can only open a phone book and pick one contact only

Comment: @Coderji let me explain you what i want, probably you can suggest me something better. I want to send alert sms to multiple contacts from phone-book(5 person only). One approach is that, i will open contact book on press of a button and one by one add all 5 contacts to edit text view. Another way will be using listview with checkbox. Can you suggest me what to do ?

Comment: @bhanukaushik check this if it helps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256932/displaying-contact-number-and-contact-name-in-a-custom-list-view