# CheckBox in List Adapter acts strange

Tags: android, list, checkbox, view, adapter

I have a list adapter , and each item has a checkbox. I also have an option to delete from that list all the items the user checks.
The part that should delete the selected items works well, but..
for example if I have

```
1. 0000
2. 5555
3. 9999
```

If I check 5555 and 9999, and click remove, they disappear but then 0000 gets checked even though I haven't pressed it.

(historyList is all the items in history fragment. listToRemove is only the checked items)

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView( LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState ) 
{ 
    View view = inflater.inflate( R.layout.fragment_history, container, false );
    adapter = new PasswordAdapter( historyList );
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    ImageView removeButton = ( ImageView ) view.findViewById( R.id.removeButton );
    removeButton.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick( View v )
        {
            if ( !listToRemove.isEmpty() )
            {
                listToRemove.clear();

                adapter.updateList( historyList );
            }
        }
    });

    return view;
}
...
...
...
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View result;

        if (convertView == null) 
        {
            result = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.history_list_item, parent, false);
        } 
        else 
        {
            result = convertView;
        }

        final Password item = getItem( position );

        ( (TextView) result.findViewById( R.id.historyPasswordTextView) ).setText(item.getPasswordString());
        ( (TextView) result.findViewById( R.id.historyDateTextView ) ).setText(item.getPasswordString());
        CheckBox checkBoxToRemove = (CheckBox) result.findViewById( R.id.removePasswordFromHistoryCheckBox ) ;
        checkBoxToRemove.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged( CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked )
                {
                    if( isChecked )
                    {
                        listToRemove.add( item );
                    //  Log.d( "TAG", listToRemove.toString() );

                        for( int i=0; i<listToRemove.size(); i++)
                            Log.d("TAG","checked after add: "+ listToRemove.get(i).getPasswordString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        listToRemove.remove( item );
                        for( int i=0; i<listToRemove.size(); i++)
                            Log.d("TAG","checked after remove: "+ listToRemove.get(i).getPasswordString());
                    }

                }
            });
```

Have I missed something?

Comment: Please share your code....

Comment: @BVtp  You have need to create a list and list item will be checkbox at position listitemclick listener make operation for checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this maybe it works

```
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final View result;
    ViewHolder holder;

            if (convertView == null) 
            {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
                convertView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.history_list_item, parent, false);

            holder. checkBoxToRemove = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById( R.id.removePasswordFromHistoryCheckBox ) ;
    convertView.setTag(holder);
            } 
            else 
            {

    holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            }

            final Password item = getItem( position );


            holder .checkBoxToRemove.setOnCheckedChangeListener( new OnCheckedChangeListener(){
                    @Override
                    public void onCheckedChanged( CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked )
                    {
                        if( isChecked )
                        {
                            listToRemove.add( item );
                        //  Log.d( "TAG", listToRemove.toString() );

                            for( int i=0; i<listToRemove.size(); i++)
                                Log.d("TAG","checked after add: "+ listToRemove.get(i).getPasswordString());
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            listToRemove.remove( item );
                            for( int i=0; i<listToRemove.size(); i++)
                                Log.d("TAG","checked after remove: "+ listToRemove.get(i).getPasswordString());
                        }

                    }
                });
return convertView;
}
     class ViewHolder {
            CheckBox checkBoxToRemove;
    }
```

And in your getView add this:

```
if(listToRemove.contains(item){
holder.checkBoxToRemove.setChecked(true);
}else{
holder.checkBoxToRemove.setChecked(false);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I think there might be something wrong though.. It shows me some error.. and btw where do you return the result here for getView ?

Comment: I copy your code and edit.  Check my edited answe now

Comment: Did you add this class ViewHolder {
            CheckBox checkBoxToRemove;
    } in your adapter class

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83329/discussion-between-amsheer-and-bvtp).

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605768/how-to-create-custom-contact-list-with-checkbox

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not use checkbox inside a `ListView`. You problem may be due to the fact that the row view are reused. I mean that the checkbox can be from a previous visible row (in your example for the row 0000 after deleting, the checkbox can be the one of the row 5555 before deleting).

I think the best way to do that is to use `onItemClickListener`. In your `onItemClick` method you add or remove item from the `listToRemove` of your adapter and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChange()`.

And in your `getView` method you draw the row according to the `listToRemove` list.

Comment: what should I replace the checkbox with?

Comment: you can leave the checkbox but disable user interaction on it. Or use an image view with two drawable for selected and not selected. My point is to not use `OnCheckedChangeListener` to handle line selection.

Comment: You could also try a CheckedTextView or a custom view that implements Checkable. Then your adapter can manage rechecking the appropriate rows based on a list of checked indexes that you maintain and update when an item's checked state has changed.