# Save state of listview with ListFragment

Tags: java, android, listview, android-contacts, android-listfragment

I try to develop an android app. I can get all contacts from phonebook to listview. But when I touch back press or button what I put under listview, it can't save.

I tried and search it but i couldn't find. Can you help me?

These are my classes.

[ContactListFragmentFragment.java](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11919570/)

[ContactListFragment.java](http://paste.ubuntu.com/11919574/)

Comment: check this post out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605768/how-to-create-custom-contact-list-with-checkbox

Comment: @KaranMer i think you understood me wrong. I try to state of listview or a hashmap when i go to other activites.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692536/good-solution-to-retain-listview-items-when-user-rotate-phone-and-keep-all-data

Comment: @KaranMer i checked it but he/she used ArrayAdapter but i use SimpleCursorAdapter.

Comment: save value of your array in shared preferences when your activity is pausing and retrive them when its resuming

Comment: @KaranMer so do you know how can disable when i changed for example from activity a to activity b and then from activity b to activity a. Activity a create again. how can i disable to destroy activity a?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84032/discussion-between-user3717742-and-karan-mer).